# how to cluster multiple csv files in a file directory

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have multiple csv files with same structure of data

[image]

i want to cluster each csv files at a time

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
import glob
df = pd.read_csv('File 000rejoice-19.csv')
can=df.drop(columns =['pat'])
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
dbscan=DBSCAN(eps=3,min_samples=4)
X = can.iloc[:, [1,2,3,4]].values
X.shape
model=dbscan.fit(X)
labels=model.labels_
sample_cores=np.zeros_like(labels,dtype=bool)
sample_cores[dbscan.core_sample_indices_]=True
n_clusters=len(set(labels))- (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_clusters
```

this code only work for one csv file,i want to cluster multiple csv files at a time

this is a jupyter notebook program
[image]

Comment: Is there any trouble in iterating each file and running your existing script against the files individually? Do you want to merge all csv files and run DBSCAN once or run it on each individual file?

Comment: i don't know how to iterate each files individually.i want to run it on each individual file.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the folder in which your csv files are located:
I'm using the  local folder `.` here.

```
from os import listdir
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

for file in listdir('.'):
  pd.read_csv(file)
  can=df.drop(columns =['pat'])
  dbscan=DBSCAN(eps=3,min_samples=4)
  X = can.iloc[:, [1,2,3,4]].values
  X.shape
  model=dbscan.fit(X)
  labels=model.labels_
  sample_cores=np.zeros_like(labels,dtype=bool)
  sample_cores[dbscan.core_sample_indices_]=True
  n_clusters=len(set(labels))- (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
  print(file, n_clusters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two steps actually here:

```
1. read multi files into DataFrame
2. use cluster to deal with DataFrame in step1
```

As @denyce has give an example for local, I could give an example for step1 with AWS S3

```
import boto3

def f(bucket, key, region_name, access_mode):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=region_name)
    s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)

    df_list = []
    s3_objs = s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key)
    for s3_prefix_obj in s3_objs:
        s3_prefix_df = s3_prefix_obj.get()['Body'].read()
        # some medium work
        df_list.append(s3_prefix_df)

    # combine data together
    df = pd.concat(s3_prefix_df_list)

    # step2, do cluster as you described, now df contains all files in s3 folder
    can=df.drop(columns =['pat'])
    dbscan=DBSCAN(eps=3,min_samples=4)
    X = can.iloc[:, [1,2,3,4]].values
    ....
```